# How do I create an Outlook rule for moving all messages flagged on a particular day?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

How do I create an Outlook rule for moving all messages flagged for follow up on a particular day?

*For example:* if a message is flagged for follow up today, I can run this rule and move it to the inbox.

**Bonus:** How can I have this rule run automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook rules can only run automatically when receiving an email, and when sending. It is also limited somehwat to which fields it can read in order to make a decision. It is possible to create a rule that picks all mails with a Follow up-flag, but it does not seem possible to separate them depending on which date they have.

There is another way, however. You may not need to move the email around. You can create Search Folders that contain all emails with a specific Due date. You could for example create the folders "Due today", "Due tomorrow", "Due next week". If that is what you would like to do, try this:
[image: custom search folder]

Opt to create a custom search folder, and then click Criterias. Choose Advanced tab, and pick the Field "Due Date" from the Task sub-menu. You can then select conditions, such as relative dates ("Tomorrow") or absolute dates. Finally, name your Search folder appropriately.

[image]

Comment: `Outlook rules can only run when receiving an email, and when sending.` Not true, you can run a rule on a particular folder on demand.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word "automatically". I changed it above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with rules, also. If you go to Advanced options.

Rules -> Create Rule - > Advanced options 
and then you select from the list the following options:

flagged for action - Select Follow up from Drop down list. Ta-Da!!!

Find the image link:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Auto-Mate Add-in for Outlook. It allows you to run rules in the background and not only when a message is sent or received like Outlook. Choose the rule type: Scan Messages after a period of time in a folder. Then choose the appropriate flag conditions that you want and the action to move the messages. The rules will run in the background and scan once per hour. You can even set the rule to scan once per day.

http://www.pergenex.com/auto-mate/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with rules, also.  If you go to

```
Rules -> Create Rule - > Advanced options
```

and then you select from the list the following options:

- received in a specific date span
- flagged for action

[image]

It does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for that. The given solution actually works, was just annoying not being able to show it with an image.

Comment: @fixer1234 Hi! thank you again for your help, here is the screenshot link: http://imgur.com/kRhgdQq

Comment: Can this be automated, as mentioned in the question?  As the accepted answer mentions, automated actions happen when the email is received.

Comment: Sorry, I only see your comment now, never got an email, but just in case, there is an ugly way to run a rule http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-rules-now-using-macro/

Answer (score 0):

The *Due Date* rule in the accepted answer was still giving me completed items for the given day, which I don't want.

Here is a rule for **items due today** that are **not completed**:

[image]

Both the *Due Date* and *Flag Status* fields can be found under Field → Frequently Used Fields.